# Generating PDFs with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I have a PHP application and a need to generate a PDF with the result of query. The easiest way a found to do this was to use the DOMPDF to generate the PDF for me. So a made a function that generates the HTML for me then a pass this to DOMPDF. In the development and testing enviroment everything was fine but on production enviroment I had some problems with memory usage.

So I would like to know if my strategy was the best one or if there's a better and easy way to do this.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I once did a PHP project generating PDF. I used [FPdf](http://www.fpdf.org/).

I never had any memory problems. It's free, it's pure PHP code. You don't have to load any extensions.

I don't know if there's some helpers to auto-generate document from a query, but in the website, you have some scripts that shows how to use it with MySql.

HTH

Comment: I can second fpdf. It worked very well for us as well.

Comment: I think FPdf is fine for me. I won't have time to refactor the code I made with DOMPDF but in the next time I'll use FPdf. Thank You all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm amazed nobody uses FOP:) http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/ ... you basically feed it an XML flie and it generates a PDF file... very quick, and dosent kill your server.

Answer (score 0):

Fll out a latex template and call Xetex over it.

I think you'll find the results pleasing at [Letterly](http://letterly.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [PDF extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php) for PHP but it's not great - however the Zend framework does have a class that makes good use of it - I reccommend trying that. I haven't heard of DOMPDF before.

Comment: As far as I know Zend_PDF does not use the ext/pdf - it's plain PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I use [EZPDF](http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/) pretty much weekly.  It's very easy to use, has great helper functions, but still lets you get in & do the nitty gritty detail work when you have to.

Answer (score 0):

PrinceXML is a good alternative. It can cost a bit, but very powerful and easy to use.