# Flatten PDFs in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, flatten

I wondered if it was possible to flatten PDFs using PHP? I use fpdf to create and collate from a collection of PDFs however when PHP has processed it some information is missing such as the comments.

I get sent several thousand PDFs every month that go on the company's website. I do need to display the comments. I know I can flatten it down in Acrobat Pro by using the JavaScript debugger ( `this.flattenPages()` ). Is there anyway to automate and save the information using PHP? As long as it's displayed on the doc I'm not too bothered.

Comment: See [Filling PDF Forms with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873/filling-pdf-forms-with-php "Filling PDF Forms with PHP"). Near exact duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of tools mentioned here, one of which might do what you want:

- [PDF Editing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/pdf-editing-in-php)
- [Generating PDFs with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265760/generating-pdfs-with-php)