# PHP Converting Excel (.xls) to pdfs

Tags: php, excel, pdf

Is there any php/java/open source software converters or php libraries that will convert an xls file to a pdf document?

Rundown: Have pre-existing code generating xls spreadsheets (circa 2002-2006, pre open xml version I believe), need to turn them into pdfs for various reasons.

Been searching everywhere including here. I think I just need a bump in the right direction, I'm sure there is something out there already that does it.

Comment: Have you considered re-factoring your code to generate straight to PDF. Rather than generating Excel spreadhseets and then attempting to convert?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265760/generating-pdfs-with-php offers a solution to generate PDFs using PHP

Comment: @MadMurf, thats what I'm hoping not to do - there is a lot of pre existing code involved. It would be what I would rather. However, refactoring isn't possible most of the time.

Comment: Fair nuff @jim, I completely understand that the re-factor isn't always available, its why I put a comment rather than an answer. The joys of maintenance on an existing code base. One point to note as you explore @Speher's solution is the performance of using OpenOffice to open/process the .XLS and output to .pdf. If its on a users workstation doing one-at-a-time no worries, however if its going to be processing requests to do this from multiple sources you might find performance & locking issues. Had fun a number of years back with MS Office in this scenario.

Comment: All of our excel report creations are one offs, daily max runs so there won't be any issue there, not for a long time at least. There may be with some automated reports but worse comes to worst I can cron edit to run them 1 min apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert XLS files to PDF on Linux by installing OpenOffice
with a PDF writer as the default printer driver.

Then, you can call OpenOffice (from PHP) using the "-p" command-line
parameter, which will cause it to load a designated file and print it.

For example, if your file was "accounts.xls" you would call the
following command:

soffice -p accounts.xls

OpenOffice would load the "accounts.xls" file and "print" it to the
PDF writer, which would be configured to save the PDF document to the
desired filename.

GhostScript is a suitable PDF writer.

The OpenOffice setup guide describes how to install and configure
printer drivers using the "spadmin" utility, and discusses the use of
ghostscript as a PDF writer:
"Open Office Setup Guide - Appendix"
http://www.openoffice.org/docs/setup_guide/appendix.html

You can call OpenOffice from PHP by using the backtick execution
operator, or the "exec" function. You may also need to use PHP to move
and/or rename the resulting PDF files:

PHP: Program Execution Functions
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php

PHP: Filesystem: Rename
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

OpenOffice is pretty good at processing XLS files, but it may not
perfectly render every such file - so if you need the ultimate in
compatibility you will have to use Microsoft Excel on a Windows
Platform or emulator. "IT AsiaOne" looked at several alternatives to
Microsoft Office (including OpenOffice) and wrote that "while none of
the alternative suites promise ... full compatibility with Microsoft
Office-created documents, in general, they do a decent job of
translating Microsoft ".doc", ".ppt" and ".xls" file formats":

IT AsiaOne - Specials - Yours For The Picking
http://it.asia1.com.sg/specials/mmedia20020724_001.html

Additional links:

OpenOffice.org Home Page
http://www.openoffice.org/

Ghostscript Home Page
http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/

PHP Home Page
http://www.php.net/

Google search strategy:

openoffice scripting pdf linux
://www.google.com/search?q=openoffice%20scripting%20pdf%20linux

openoffice print "command line"
://www.google.com/search?q=openoffice%20scripting%20pdf%20linux

followed by a search for "command line parameters" from the
openoffice.org home page.

ref: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/177241.html

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP is able to execute commands via shell in linux, **[this](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/177241.html)** could be a good start.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks, will report back when I've tested it out!

Comment: Had a few network issues with the install.. then I had a few other things todo, will see how things go tomorrow! I think I have to figure out the configs and edit them by hand too.