# Upload a file on doc and change into image file on server

Tags: php, android, mysql, server

i am working on a app where there is a need to upload doc file(.xls/.xlsx/.doc/.docx) on server and convert into Image using php code . Can anybody suggest me how i can convert any doc file to image and saved it to server .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Doc can't convert into image and why you want this kind of functionality ?

Comment: Please refer this link might be helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708534/create-a-thumbnail-preview-of-documents-pdf-doc-xls-etc-in-php-lamp

Comment: Thanks Lalit Sharma . Can you please give some code link for php code. Thanks for your valuable response .