# take screenshot from a uploaded file with php

Tags: php, file, screenshot

I'm continuing with my script to upload files, so on a html form, it askes to upload a file, and then there is a table where I can view the file as it is save it in the db (well, it saves the path) and I was wondering... is it possible to take a screenshot of the file I'm uploading to show it on an html table?

I mean... is there any php function which takes an screenshot/image of a file?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why take a screen shot? Why not just show the image?

Comment: It depends on which kind of file. If is an image you can show it as it is or maybe crop it & generate a thumbs using a built in library, if is a PDF or DOCX you need somthing to open PDF's and MS Word documents in the first place

Comment: If it is an image you could just use the image data in the src tag while the file is uploading

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708534/create-a-thumbnail-preview-of-documents-pdf-doc-xls-etc-in-php-lamp

Comment: well yes I mean that, to show the image, but the file I'm uploading can me an image, a pdf..anything! that's why I've though on a screenshot.

I don't need anything to open pdf's or docx, or at least I haven't put anything, I've just added the path for each file as anchor tag and it works perfectly. 

It is just I wanted to do the html table with all the records to look nice, and before to add an input to upload an screenshot (for identifying purposes only), I've though it might be a function that does it?