# "avery" type templates in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I want to print some stuff on to labels of a predefined size. Can the layout be done in the browser and printed?

Obviously the problem is that it seems that size is not guaranteed when printing from the browser.

Avery only provides word doc templates (possibly for this reason)

**Question:**
Can layout dimensions be guaranteed when printing an HTML only template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: Can layout dimensions be guaranteed when printing an HTML only template?

In theory yes, through CSS and by using a print stylesheet.

In practice no, for example because browsers tend to add (and reserve space for) their own headers and footers.

Generating a PDF would be a way, way more reliable way for label printing.

If you still want to do it in HTML, these will help:

- [Good rules for setting up print css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401623/good-rules-for-setting-up-print-css)
- [Print stylesheets tutorial](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets)

Some good questions to get you started on PDF generation:

- [Generate PDF report from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417315/generate-pdf-report-from-php)
- [Generating PDFs with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265760/generating-pdfs-with-php)