# how to transfer data from table to pdf in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating PDFs with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265760/generating-pdfs-with-php)

how to transfer data from table to pdf?
or is there other ways to print reports from table
this is my current table i want it to transfer on pdf

```
$tbl_select_exp=mysql_query("select * from expeditures where Date between '$date1' and '$date2' and active= '1' order by        Date ASC"); 
    while($test = mysql_fetch_array($tbl_select_exp))
   {
    ?><tr id="<?php  echo  $test['ExpenseID'] ?>" onclick="a(this.id); myfunction(this)">
    <?php
    echo"<td>".$test['Date']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$test['ORno']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$test['AccountName']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$test['Amount']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
    $test++;    
   }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but why does this have 4 upvotes?

Answer (score 0):

For simple PDF take a look at FPDF library, for more advanced features check tcPDF and mPDF.

Answer (score 0):

I use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) its a very simple command line tool which makes a pdf file from your HTML sources.

From your script you can call it with exec or you can google for helper classes.

I like it and the CSS support is very cool.

Comment: can you make a simple guide or codes?